# Using Eclipse for C programming?

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

I want to examine and modify some open source programs written in C.

Is it sensible to use Eclipse for this purpose? If so, what plugins should I add? What "gotchas" should I be aware of?

If not, what FOSS C IDEs do you recommend for coding C on a linux box? Emacs, while undeniably powerful, is not to my taste (I'm more a mouser than a keyboarder.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found netbeans to be a better ide for C/C++ then eclipse -- C/C++ is a first class citizen in the netbeans world. I am personally using [geany](http://www.geany.org/) these days.

Comment: I am sorry but geany is quite disappointing ... It doesnt have indexing mechanisms and quite lame like a gedit ... Just one more editor .. If you have any link to properly configure it then it would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse CDT, you can download Eclipse IDE for C/C++  [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) . Its not as mature as the Java IDE, and it can be a pain to set up a proper build system with it unless you're happy letting Eclipse handle your builds.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for alternative open source IDEs, I would recommend Code::Blocks for anything C/C++.

If you want to give it a try, download a [nightly build](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=075c054651721761d683e0985a3e5681&board=20.0) (they don't really keep the "stable" version up-to-date). You can find instructions for installing on Linux in the respective forum thread.

IMO Code::Blocks is really nice because it's fast, portable and you can configure every detail of your project easily. There are also lots of [plugins](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_Plugins) that can help you with development.

*But* if you're accustomed to Eclipse and like it so far, you should really use [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) because you get the same (nice) look-and-feel as with the other Eclipse development environments (Java, Java EE, Jython, Python, ...).

Comment: (IMO) On code::blocks, everything is so hidden and terse. A good piece of software should have a person working from the get-go.

Comment: Opinions differ. Therefore he should try all of the mentioned IDEs to find out what fits best.